# VHDL 4-bit multiplier based on 4-bit adder

Tags: vhdl, fpga, multiplication

i am a bit new to VHDL and i try to learn by examples. So long story short i began with some basic examples like creating this Full Adder.
[image]

```
 entity FA is
 Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC;
    B : in STD_LOGIC;
    Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
    S : out STD_LOGIC;
    Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end FA;

architecture gate_level of FA is

begin

 S <= A XOR B XOR Cin ;
 Cout <= (A AND B) OR (Cin AND A) OR (Cin AND B) ;

end gate_level;
```

After that i tried to implement this 4-bit adder

[image]

And this is the code that i wrote.

```
entity Ripple_Adder is
Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
S : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end Ripple_Adder;

architecture Behavioral of Ripple_Adder is

-- Full Adder VHDL Code Component Decalaration
component FA
Port (  A : in STD_LOGIC;
    B : in STD_LOGIC;
    Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
    S : out STD_LOGIC;
    Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

-- Intermediate Carry declaration
signal c1,c2,c3: STD_LOGIC;

begin

-- Port Mapping Full Adder 4 times
FA1: FA port map( A(0), B(0), Cin, S(0), c1);
FA2: FA port map( A(1), B(1), c1, S(1), c2);
FA3: FA port map( A(2), B(2), c2, S(2), c3);
FA4: FA port map( A(3), B(3), c3, S(3), Cout);

end Behavioral;
```

Also i used a 4_bit_adder test bench file and i found out that the output is right. Now i am trying to implement a 4 bit multiplier with the usage of the 4 bit adder but i am a bit stuck. Actually this is the multiplier that i am trying to implement.[image]

the code i wrote is this, but i am stuck at the port map

```
--library
library IEEE;
   use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
   use IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
   use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

--entity
entity multy is
  port (x: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        y: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        p : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
        );
end multy ;

-- architecture
architecture rtl of multy is
component Ripple_Adder
  Port ( A : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
     B : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
     Cin : in std_logic;
     S : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
     Cout : out std_logic);
end component ;

signal andgate: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal sumout: std_logic_vector( 11 downto 0);
signal carry: std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);


begin
    andgate(0) <= x(0) and y(0);
    andgate(1) <= x(1) and y(0); --b0
    andgate(2) <= x(2) and y(0); --b1
    andgate(3) <= x(3) and y(0); --b2
B

    andgate(4) <= x(0) and y(1);
    andgate(5) <= x(1) and y(1);
    andgate(6) <= x(2) and y(1);
    andgate(7) <= x(3) and y(1);

    andgate(8) <= x(0) and y(2);
    andgate(9) <= x(1) and y(2);
    andgate(10) <= x(2) and y(2);
    andgate(11) <= x(3) and y(2);

    andgate(12) <= x(0) and y(3);
    andgate(13) <= x(1) and y(3);
    andgate(14) <= x(2) and y(3);
    andgate(15) <= x(3) and y(3);

--gates


cell_1: Ripple_Adder port map();
cell_2: Ripple_Adder port map();
cell_3: Ripple_Adder port map();


 --Assigning p values
    p(0) <= andgate(0);
    p(1) <= sumout(0);
    p(2) <= sumout(4);
    p(3) <= sumout(8);
    p(4) <= sumout(9);
    p(5) <= sumout(10);
    p(6) <= sumout(11);
    p(7) <= carry(11);

end rtl ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"I am stuck on the port map"* isn't a specific problem statement.

With named association members of formal ports in maps could be associated *individually* as well as in *whole* as long as all members of the formal are associated - IEEE Std 1076-2008  6.5.7 Association lists:

> A formal interface object shall be either an explicitly declared interface object or member (see 5.1) of such an interface object. In the former case, such a formal is said to be *associated in whole*. In the latter cases, named association shall be used to associate the formal and actual; the subelements of such a formal are said to be *associated individually*. Furthermore, every scalar subelement of the explicitly declared interface object shall be associated exactly once with an actual (or subelement thereof) in the same association list, and all such associations shall appear in a contiguous sequence within that association list. Each association element that associates a slice or subelement (or slice thereof) of an interface object shall identify the formal with a locally static name.

Note you have too many carry elements (only need two), don't need andgate(0), don't need sumout(0), sumout(4) or  sumout(11 downo 8), there's an extraneous character in the multy architecture, you're missing context clauses and have unused use clauses.

Your code using array intermediary signals:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;   -- NOT USED
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; -- NOT USED

entity multy is 
    port (
        x: in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        y: in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        p: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
    );
end entity multy;

architecture rtl of multy is
    component Ripple_Adder
        port ( 
            A:      in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
            B:      in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
            Cin:    in  std_logic;
            S:      out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
           Cout:    out std_logic
        );
    end component;
-- AND Product terms:
    signal G0, G1, G2:  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
-- B Inputs (B0 has three bits of AND product)
    signal B0, B1, B2:  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

begin

    -- y(1) thru y (3) AND products, assigned aggregates:
    G0 <= (x(3) and y(1), x(2) and y(1), x(1) and y(1), x(0) and y(1));
    G1 <= (x(3) and y(2), x(2) and y(2), x(1) and y(2), x(0) and y(2));
    G2 <= (x(3) and y(3), x(2) and y(3), x(1) and y(3), x(0) and y(3));
    -- y(0) AND products (and y0(3) '0'):
    B0 <=  ('0',          x(3) and y(0), x(2) and y(0), x(1) and y(0));

-- named association:
cell_1: 
    Ripple_Adder 
        port map (
            a => G0,
            b => B0,
            cin => '0',
            cout => B1(3), -- named association can be in any order
            S(3) => B1(2), -- individual elements of S, all are associated
            S(2) => B1(1), -- all formal members must be provide contiguously
            S(1) => B1(0),
            S(0) => p(1)
        );
cell_2: 
    Ripple_Adder 
        port map (
            a => G1,
            b => B1,
            cin => '0',
            cout => B2(3),
            S(3) => B2(2),
            S(2) => B2(1),
            S(1) => B2(0),
            S(0) => p(2)
        );
cell_3: 
    Ripple_Adder 
        port map (
            a => G2,
            b => B2,
            cin => '0',
            cout => p(7),
            S => p(6 downto 3)  -- matching elements for formal
        );
    p(0) <= x(0) and y(0); 
end architecture rtl;
```

And a borrowed testbench to demonstrate:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity multy_tb is           -- testbench
end entity;

architecture foo of multy_tb is
    signal x, y:        std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal yp, rp:      std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;

begin
DUT:
    entity work.multy
        port map (
            x => x,
            y => y,
            p => yp
        );
STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        for i in 0 to 15 loop
            x <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, x'length));
            for j in 0 to 15 loop
                y <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(j, y'length));
                wait for 0 ns; -- assignments take effect
                rp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned (x) * unsigned(y));
                wait for 10 ns;
                if yp /= rp then
                    report "multy error";
                    report HT & "expected " & to_string (rp);
                    report HT & "got      " & to_string (yp);
                end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The to_string function is included for pre -2008 simulators. Context clauses were added to FA and Ripple_Adder.

Comment: This is what i really wanted.
Your explanation was really helpful and it really helped me to understand a lot.
Mainly i was confused on how can i add `y(1) thru y (3) AND products` to `a` or `b` inputs.
Thank you again.